# Bind several Persistent Volume Claims to one mount path

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-pvc

I am working on an application on Kubernetes in GCP and I need a really huge SSD storage for it.

So I created a `StorageClass` recourse, a `PersistentVolumeClaim` that requests 500Gi of space and then a `Deployment` recourse.

StorageClass.yaml:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: faster
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
```

PVC.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongo-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: faster
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Gi
```

Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo
        name: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data/db
          name: mongo-volume
      volumes:
      - name: mongo-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongo-volume
```

When I applied the PVC, it stuck in `Pending...` state for hours. I found out experimentally that it binds correctly with maximum 200Gi of requested storage space.

However, I can create several 200Gi PVCs. Is there a way to bind them to one path to work as one big PVC in Deployment.yaml? Or maybe the 200Gi limit can be expanded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested it on my own env and it works perfectly. So the problem is in Quotas.

For this check:

IAM & admin -> Quotas -> Compute Engine API Local SSD (GB) "your region" 
Amount which you used.

I've created the situation when I`m run out of Quota and it stack in pending status the same as your. 
It happens because you create PVC for each pod for 500GB each.

Comment: I've checked Quotas and I guess my limit is okay...
[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/Cgn4zYL)

Comment: hmm, it is strange, could you try to use [this template](https://github.com/thesandlord/mongo-k8s-sidecar/tree/master/example/StatefulSet) with StatefulSet. Have the same problem with volumes?

Comment: Yes, volumes are still stuck in Pending.

Comment: I've just check it for my self if I decrease quota it stack because I'm run out of quota. Please double check your quotas it depends on regions in each region you have dedicated quota and there quota for type of disk(HDD, SSD).

Comment: I've changed the metric to Persistent Disk SSD and it is indeed out of quota in my region. Thanks!